# How to iterate through a list using subproperties in Flutter? Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, return, widget

I'm trying to iterate through list to render multiple widgets. The list is setup so every item has 2 sub-properties, I'm trying to use the .map property to make this work.

I've tried this before with another project and it worked, but this time there's a change with the consistency of sub properties (certain numbers of the list  have more that 2 sub-properties).

```
    var storyMap = [
{
  "story":
      "Your car...",
  "answer": [
    ["I'll hop...", 1],
    ["Better ask...", 1],
  ]
},
{
  "story": "He nods...",
  "answer": [
    ["At least...", 1],
    ["Wait, I...", 1],
  ]
},
{
  "story":
      "As you...",
  "answer": [
    ["I love...", 1],
  ],
},
```

];

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CupertinoApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ...(storyMap[storyMapIndex]["answer"]
                      as List<Map<String, Object>>)
                  .map((number) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CupertinoButton(
                      child: Text(number[1]),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          storyMapIndex += number[2];
                        }); //return
                      },
                    ), 
                  ], //<Widget>[]
                ); //Column
              }).toList(),
            ], ////<Widget>[]
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
); //cupertino app
```

}

//better looking code file is in here
https://github.com/Pshah2023/Destini-App

I wanted this to iterate through every item in the list, look at sub properties and use it properly. This din't work and it gave the error

Object isn't a subtype of String.

Probably from the line with List> (but I can't change that line or it will iterate through the wrong items)

Comment: It looks to me like there's a mismatch between your data and how you're using it. specifically, the `"answer"` keys in your data is a `List` of `List<String>`, but in your build method, you're treating it as a `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Do you want answers to be a `Map` or a `List`?

Comment: I’m trying to use a list of maps, to get a list, so I want the list stored in  “answer”.